# Create Azure API App without Swagger.io

Tags: java, azure, jax-rs, swagger

I'm using Azure for the first time and wanting to make a very simple RESTful API, but trying to follow the [example using Swagger.io](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-java-api-app/) feels like a lot of work for what I want to achieve. Is there a way to just write Java code for JAX-RX without going through the Swagger.io generator process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service description stating that you can bring your API as is:

> Bring your existing API as-is - You don't have to change any of the
>   code in your existing APIs to take advantage of API Apps -- just
>   deploy your code to an API app. Your API can use any language or
>   framework supported by App Service, including ASP.NET and C#, Java,
>   PHP, Node.js, and Python.

Swagger support facilitate ease of consumption, since you able to auto generate client sdks in various languages based on swagger spec. Nothing prevent you not having  swagger and still use service.